# Variable is already defined in method lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Consider the following *almost* compilable Java 8 code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList<User> users = null;
    users.add(new User(1, "User1"));
    users.add(new User(2, "User2"));
    users.add(new User(3, "User3"));

    User user = users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId() == 1).findAny().get();
}

static class User {

    int id;
    String username;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, String username) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

You'll notice `User user = users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId() == 1).findAny().get();` throws a compiler error:

> variable user is already defined in method main(String[])

My question is: Why do Lambda expressions consider the variable that is *being initialized* on the same line as the Lambda expression as already defined? I understand Lambdas look outside themselves for (and use) local variables, so you can't name the variables you use inside the Lambda the same as an outside variable. But why is the variable that is *being* defined considered *already* defined?

Comment: Declaration happens before initialization. Your local variable `user` is defined before `user` is in the lambda expression.

Comment: @MirroredFate I think the point is that the lambda expression `user` argument is actually expected to be used within a totally different context (the evaluation context of the expression), and so why should it be affected by the `user` variable defined outside?

Comment: The only argument I can think of as of now is that the variable `user` is part of the closure environment, it is already within the context of the lambda expression, and so, if you declare another variable `user`, there is a name conflict. However, I still wonder, why was it not simply shadowed. Can this be related to how things are instrumented under the hood?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo His question is *why is the variable that is being defined considered already defined?*, and my comment was attempting to explain that.

Comment: You are mixing up declaration and initialization. The variable is *declared* before it is initialized. And for the lambda within the intializer the variable `user` is declared though not yet initialized. This is the same for local variables without lambdas, e.g. for `int x=x+1;` the second `x` will refer to the variable `x` which is already *declared* but the reference is invalid as `x` is not *initialized* at that point. There will be no attempt to find an initialized `x` in an outer scope.

Comment: @ryvantage Well, what happened to the Sunrise? I was about to post that the program runs into a NaN.

Comment: @laune, I deleted the question because it was trivial. You can email me your solution at ryan at vantagecp dot com

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's go to the Java Language Specification on [names and their scopes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)

> The scope of a formal parameter of a method (§8.4.1), constructor
>   (§8.8.1), or lambda expression (§15.27) is the entire body of the
>   method, constructor, or lambda expression.
>
> The **scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.4) is the
>   rest of the block in which the declaration appears**, starting with its
>   own initializer **and including any further declarators to the right in
>   the local variable declaration statement.**

Then, on the subject of [shadowing and obscuring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4)

> A local variable (§14.4), formal parameter (§8.4.1, §15.27.1),
>   exception parameter (§14.20), and local class (§14.3) can only be
>   referred to using a simple name, not a qualified name (§6.2).
>
> Some declarations are not permitted within the scope of a local
>   variable, formal parameter, exception parameter, or local class
>   declaration because it would be impossible to distinguish between the
>   declared entities using only simple names.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if the name of a local variable v is used
>   to declare a new variable within the scope of v, unless the new
>   variable is declared within a class whose declaration is within the
>   scope of v.**

So, in

```
User user = users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId() == 1).findAny().get();
```

, the scope of the variable `user` is everything after it in that block. Now you are trying to use the name of that variable to declare a new variable within the scope, but not

> **within a class whose declaration is within the scope of v.**

so a compile time error occurs. (It's declared in a lambda expression, not in a class.)

Answer (score 8):

look at the code

```
User user = users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId() == 1).findAny().get();
```

The variable name is `user` and the variable inside the lambda is also `user`

try changing it to be something like this

```
User user = users.stream().filter((otherUser) -> otherUser.getId() == 1).findAny().get();
```

Comment: Uhm, I think the OP is aware of that

Comment: Yeah, I think the question is why isn't the lambda `user` variable shadowing the `user` variable in the closure context? Otherwise this question is boring.

Answer (score 4):

Note, this limitation is going to be removed in the future releases. Quote from [JEP-302](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/302):

> Lambda parameters are not allowed to shadow variables in the enclosing scopes. (In other words, a lambda behaves like a for statement - see JLS) This often causes problems, as in the following (very common) case:

```
Map<String, Integer> msi = ...
...
String key = computeSomeKey();
msi.computeIfAbsent(key, key -> key.length()) //error
```

> Here, the attempt to reuse the name key as a lambda parameter in the computeIfAbsent call fails, as a variable with the same name was already defined in the enclosing context.
>
> It would be desirable to lift this restriction, and allow lambda parameters (and locals declared with a lambda) to shadow variables defined in enclosing scopes. (One possible argument against is readability: if lambda parameters are allowed to shadow, then in the above example, the identifier 'key' means two different things in the two places where it is used, and there seem to be no syntactic barrier to separate the two usages.)

Comment: That's cool. Slightly less related to the topic at hand, though, in that the identifier in my example _doesn't_ mean two different things because the outer variable is _being initialized_ by the lambda in the same line as the declaration. In other words, the outer variable can only be used once the lambda is finished, thus creating said missing syntactic barrier.

Answer (score 3):

It is the same as with any other local variables: you're not allowed to shadow them in more inner {} blocks.

Answer (score -1):

The question is pretty old, but i thought my answer can add better clarity to the already given answers. Particularly to that of @Sotirios Delimanolis . 
The lambda assignment in

```
    User user = users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId() == 1).findAny().get();
```

fails for the same reason the following code fails.

```
    Object e = null;
    try{
      throw new Exception();
    } catch(Exception e) { // compilation fails because of duplicate declaration
      //do nothing
    }
```

> A local variable (§14.4), formal parameter (§8.4.1, §15.27.1), exception parameter (§14.20), and local class (§14.3) can only be referred to using a simple name, not a qualified name (§6.2).
>
> Some declarations are not permitted within the scope of a local variable, formal parameter, exception parameter, or local class declaration because it would be **impossible to distinguish between the declared entities using only simple names**.

Because lambdas have the same scope of all the things mentioned above, this fails.

Comment: "impossible to distinguish" I disagree. The `User user` that is _being initialized_ is certainly unusable (e.g., `BigDecimal x = x.plus(y)` is obviously erroneous). So it doesn't seem like a huge stretch to say that the `user` variable within the lambda is obviously not referring to the variable that is currently being initialized. And thus the compiler should be able to grant you the ability to use the same name.

Comment: Logically speaking, you are right. But java semantics just doesn't use that kind of an inference in lambdas or any of the declarations. The java compiler couldn't distinguish between a forward reference and a lambda parameter. By the way Impossible to distinguish is from the JLS, if that is what you downvoted the answer for.

Comment: Dude, I know. The question stated clearly that I understand that you can’t, but _why_ they specifically decided to make the scope of variable names so specific as to exclude obvious situations where there is no conflict is still a mystery. Again, clearly, they specifically decided to make this specification but there seems to be no obvious reason why. Your answer adds nothing new. The only kind of new answer left to provide is a situation where the compiler, by limiting you, is preventing an error.

Comment: Can you think of a situation where, if you were allowed to name an inner lambda variable the same thing as the variable being initialized, it would lead to a runtime error?

Comment: Because a lambda is just another block, it doesn't have a context of its own. Section [15.27.2 Lambda Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) 
specifies that _Unlike code appearing in anonymous class declarations, the meaning of names and the **this** and **super** keywords appearing in a lambda body, along with the accessibility of referenced declarations, are the same as in the surrounding context (except that lambda parameters introduce new names)._

Comment: And for **Why a lambda is not as same as an anonymous class**, the JVM treats a lambda quite differently from a normal object, it lets you handle them as if they were objects, But the JVM is not required to implement them as such.