# Java lambda parameter name issue

Tags: java, lambda, scope, java-8

It seems that Java 8 doesn't accept a lambda parameter name with the same name as the variable that is assigned later by the same instruction.

See code below that compiles:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d"));
String e = list.stream().map(e2 -> { return e2 + "x"; }).findFirst().get();
```

The same code doesn't compile when lambda parameter 'e2' is renamed into 'e'.
The same would work with other functional language such as OCaml.

The same also would work if I don't use lambda syntax and write an anonymous class:

```
String e = list.stream().map(new Function<String, String>() {
    public String apply(String e) {
        return e + "x";
    }
}).findFirst().get();
```

Is there a good reason for that?
Otherwise, I would be very happy if someone would give a word to Oracle.

Comment: The duplicate explains the language rule, but not the reason behind it. If that's what you're asking about, we can re-open.

Comment: [Though Stuart Marks does explain some reasoning in the comments.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773003/variable-is-already-defined-in-method-lambda#comment34722982_22774258)