# Java Lambda expression error

Tags: java, lambda

In my Java 8 code,

```
public ChangePersonsName(String email, final String password, final String wantedUsername, final String uuid, final long time, int latency, int[] requests, int[] proxyRequests) throws IOException {
    final AtomicReference<Object> token = new AtomicReference<Object>();
    final AtomicReference<ArrayList<?>> newHeaders = new AtomicReference<ArrayList<?>>();
    new Thread(() -> {
        boolean lock = true;
        while (lock) {
            if (time - System.currentTimeMillis() > 60000) continue;
            Map<Header[], String> loginResults = null;
            try {
                loginResults = this.login(email, password, uuid);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           String token = loginResults.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue();
            Header[] headers = loginResults.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey();
            newHeaders.set(new ArrayList<Object>());
            for (Header header : headers) {
                if (!header.toString().startsWith("Set-Cookie:")) continue;
                ((List<BasicHeader>)newHeaders.get()).add(new BasicHeader("Cookie", header.toString().split("Set-Cookie: ")[1]));
            }
            lock = false;
        }
    }
    ).start();
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
```

You'll notice that

```
String token = loginResults.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue();
```

throws a compile error,

> Lambda expression's local variable token cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope.

My question is, How would one go about fixing this? I'm pretty new to Java, I should probably know how to fix this, but i don't.

Comment: `final AtomicReference<Object> token = new AtomicReference<Object>();` You have two variable with the same name (`token`). This is said in the message _local variable **token** cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope._

Comment: *"How would one go about fixing this?"* Name it something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [variable is already defined in method lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773003/variable-is-already-defined-in-method-lambda)

Answer (score 5):

You already have variable with name `token` in this scope. You've declared it in 2nd row. To fix just rename 2nd variable:

```
String newToken = loginResults.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue();
```