# How to aggregate values in an array of objects in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I store documents from cars and want to get the temperature of all Mercedes cars as an array, how should the query be in Mongodb?

```
 { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5880ff305d15f416c89457b7" },
     "car" : "mercedes",
      "engine" : { 
            "sensor" : {
                        "temperatur" : "20",
                        "speed" : "100", 
                        "hue" : "40" 
                        }
                },
         "motor" : {
                    "Power" : "155", 
                    "Topspeed" : "400" 
                    } 
}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5880ff305d15f416c89457b7" },
     "car" : "mercedes",
      "engine" : { 
            "sensor" : {
                        "temperatur" : "50",
                        "speed" : "100", 
                        "hue" : "40" 
                        }
                },
         "motor" : {
                    "Power" : "155", 
                    "Topspeed" : "400" 
                    } 
}
```

I would like to select the temperature for all Mercedes cars and receive it.
result should be like [20,50]

EDIT:
My code lookls like the following iam using JAVA:

```
  MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
      MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
      MongoCollection<Document> coll = database.getCollection("myTestCollection");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this with regular query if you're okay with distinct values.

```
db.cars.distinct("engine.sensor.temperatur", {"car" : "mercedes"});
```

This will give you

```
[ "20", "50" ]
```

Update - Java equivalent:

```
List<String> temps = coll.distinct("engine.sensor.temperatur", new Document("car", "mercedes"), String.class).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Update - Aggregation Option

```
Bson match = new Document("$match", new Document("car", "mercedes"));

Bson group = new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$car").append("temps", new Document("$push", "$engine.sensor.temperatur")));

List<String> temps  = (List<String>) coll.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, group)).map(document -> document.get("temps")).first();
```

Comment: does cars mean the collection name? and how should I do this with my test database and myTestCollection collection?

Comment: yes it is. Just replace `cars` with `myTestCollection`

Comment: and db? should I replace it with database? I get an error. syntax error  on tokes(s), misplaced contruct

Comment: First change to `test` db. Something like `use test` and then run the query. Added the java equivalent too to the answer.

Comment: That was for mongo console query.

Comment: could you please provide me an example with all values and not distinct? I tried aggregate, but its not working

Comment: Updated with aggregation option.

Comment: error on "document ->"       "Lambda expression's parameter document cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope. "

Comment: You've code where `document` is already defined. You can rename this lambda variable if it is conflicting. See if you can relate your issue to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773003/variable-is-already-defined-in-method-lambda