# Replace functional interface with Function

Tags: java, lambda

I'm a bit confused with this code. Why not compile?

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Inter {
  BigDecimal method (BigDecimal param);
}

public class Main {
  public static void main {
    Function<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> func = param -> BigDecimal.ZERO;
    Inter i1 = param -> BigDecimal.ZERO; // compile
    Inter i2 = func; // not compile
  }
}
```

Comment: @CommonMan it's not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException, Op is not able to compile the last line because of `Lambda expression's parameter func cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope. ` , The answer to above error is mentioned in link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773003/variable-is-already-defined-in-method-lambda , so it is duplicate, isnt it?

Comment: @CommonMan no, it's not because "Lambda expression's parameter func cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope." `func` is not a lambda expression parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [package java.util.function description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html#package.description).

> Functional interfaces provide target types for lambda expressions and method references.

That doesn't imply that functional interfaces are target types for variables of arbitrary concrete classes (such as `Function<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>` in your case).

To use a `Function<>` (in your case, in a variable called `func`) in a context that requires a specific functional interface (`Inter`) you can simply make it a lambda or a method reference:

```
Inter i2 = p -> func.apply(p);  // compiles
```

or

```
Inter i2 = func::apply;
```

Comment: Ok, and is there any way to convert one type into the other?

Comment: Sorry, but not compile: The method func(BigDecimal) is undefined

Comment: @user1151816 sorry, should've been `func.apply(p)`, now corrected.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I've just added an alternative to your answer using a method reference.

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 functional interfaces(SAM) here,
first is Inter and second is FunctionalInterface which is provided by java and it represents a function that accepts one argument and produces a result.

Looking at `Inter i2 = func;` line ,  what you are trying to do here is assigning one Functional Interface  to other Functional Interface, which doesn't make any sense here.

I have modified your code and introduce a new functional interface, hope this helps and clears your doubt.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Inter {
    BigDecimal method (BigDecimal param);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Function<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> func = param -> BigDecimal.ZERO;

    Inter i1 = param -> BigDecimal.ZERO; // compile

    //creating new functional interface which returns Inter lambda body.
    Supplier<Inter> interSuppFuncInter = () -> { return param -> BigDecimal.ZERO; };

    Inter i2 = interSuppFuncInter.get(); // now compile's
    System.out.println(i2.method(BigDecimal.ZERO)); // invoke i2 lambda by calling its  method and passing the param
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`func` is a `Function<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>`, which is not a sub-interface of `Inter`. Therefore it cannot be assigned to an `Inter` variable.

The fact that both `Inter` and `Function<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>` are functional interfaces having a method with the same signature doesn't matter, since they are not related.